# Transforming a NxN binary matrix to a zero matrix using minimum row and column toggles

Tags: algorithm, matrix

This is about the question i posted regarding converting one NxN binary matrix to another . The question i asked is a code-challenge problem . However, a similar question was asked at [How to do matrix conversions by row and columns toggles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310590/matrix-conversion). I went through that thread,and have gained some idea about how to go about solving the problem.
I restate the problem here.

"I want to write code to solve the following problem. I am planning to use C, C++, Java or Python, depending on whichever allows a more convenient solution.
Given two NxN (1 <= N <= 2000) binary matrices (A matrix each of whose element is either a one or a zero), A and B. The problem is to transform A into B, using the minimum number of permissible operations.
The permissible operations are:
1. We can toggle a row,
   which will toggle all values in that row, i.e. it will change 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 in that row
2. We can toggle a column,
   which will toggle all values in that column, i.e. it will change 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 in that column.
If no solution is possible we print -1"

However, i have the following doubt.

I understood that the first step in finding the minimum number of toggles required to transform A to B is calculating A XOR B .The 1's in the result are the places which have to be toggled, in other words A XOR B has to be transformed to a zero matrix using the minimum number of row and column toggles . However, its not clear to me, how A XOR B is to be transformed to zero matrix , using the minimum number of row and column toggles. Could someone please shed some light on that ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

Fairly easy task.

First, we should understand that **there is no sense in switching a row or a column more than once**.  For better understanding, we denote state like that: each cell has 0 or 1 in it and always take result of the sum with modulo 2:

```
final[i,j] = initial[i,j] + row_switched[i] + column_switched[j]  (mod 2)
```

where `row_switched` and `column_switched` are numbers of times we switched i-th row and j-th column.  Now it's clear, that their values should be 0 or 1 to get minimal number of switches.

But that actually makes... a system of equations! We know initial states (given), we know final states (zeros), we only need to solve the system against `r[i]` and `c[j]`!

Unfortunately, it's still complex to solve because of moduli and because it doesn't include constraints implied on `r[i]` and `c[j]` (being 0 or 1).

---

Let's rewrite these condition without modulus:

```
row_switched[i] + column_switched[j] = 1  (if initial[i,j] = 1)
row_switched[i] - column_switched[j] = 0  (if initial[i,j] = 0)
```

Having written this for each cell, we have gotten an overdefined system of N^2 equations.  Let's solve it in the following method.  It's clear that if we knew the value of `row_switched[0]`, we would then know the values of the whole `column_switched[]` array, because they're unambiguously deduced by the equations, in which `row_switched[0]` takes part.  Then it's easy to deduce value of every row as well.

But we have only two variants for `row_switched[0]`: 0 and 1.  Let's try each of them (SEE NOTE BELOW), and for each, calculate both arrays!  Then we should **check that all the equations hold** and choose one of two sets that satisfies the **whole** system **and has less switches**.

If neither satisfies it, then, well, it's unsolvable.  Try to solve this one, heh:

```
0 1
0 0
```

This completes the solution.  I hope you'll do a +1 just for trying. :)

---

On the question why this is the least possible number of switches.  Indeed, any *valid* number of switches  should satisfy the system of equations outlined above (with 0 and 1 as constraints for values).  But that system has not more than two solutions, and **we find them all in the algorithm above**.  So, the algorithm above surely finds the minimal one.

---

**NOTE**:
It *seems* to me, that we can only try one of set.  If one passes the system, the other should pass as well.  One set is a negation of another, so we just choose the set with less switch number.  Sum of switches is 2N.  But this only *seems* and is less clear than the other part.

Comment: If my answer is too long for you to read it, please, vote this comment up! :-)  I need feedback. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let me take another shot at explaining the end of my answer back in [How to do matrix conversions by row and columns toggles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310590/matrix-conversion).

We've reduced the problem to converting a matrix to the zero matrix via toggles, if possible.  Start by noting that, if we want a minimal answer, we'll never toggle a row or column more than once, since toggling a row/column twice is the same as not toggling to begin with -- a consequence of the identity (P XOR 1) XOR 1 = P.

Let's look at the first row.  Every 1 in the first row must be toggled to 0.  We can do that by toggling each column with a 1 in the first row, *or* we can toggle the first row, swapping the 1's and 0's, and then toggle each new 1 back to a 0.  And (assuming no toggle pairs) those are the *only* two sets of operations that result in the first row being reduced to all 0's.

At this point, look at the other rows.  If any row has a mixture of 0's or 1's, you're done and the problem is insoluble; there is no way to make the row all 0's without a column toggle, and that destroys a 0 in the first row.  OTOH, if every other row is all 0's or all 1's, then you just have row toggles remaining.

The final step is a consequence of the fact that there are 2N possible toggles, and no toggle will be part of both solutions.  That should be immediately clear from the above for column toggles; for row toggles, note that a row that is all 0's after one set of column toggles will be all 1's after the other set of column toggles.  So, after computing one set of K toggles, the size of the other set will be 2N - K toggles.