# Matrix of 0s and 1s. Minimize number of operations

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I came across this problem at [codechef](http://codechef.com) long ago but I'm unable to locate it now. I'm at my wits' end in trying to solve this problem.

You are given a matrix containing only 0s and 1s. An operation OP can be applied to an element in the matrix 
 which toggles that element and every element in that row and column. After applying the operation **X** times, the resulting matrix should contain only 0s or only 1s. Output the minimum value of **X** to fulfill the requirement. Output -1 if it's not possible.

E.g.

```
1 0
0 1
```

Apply OP on M[0][0] =>

```
0 1
1 1
```

OP on M[1][1] =>

```
0 0
0 0
```

How do you go about solving this?
If you know where this question resides on codechef, a link would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your approach to solve this?

Comment: I couldn't develop an approach to solve it. Brute force isn't an option here. And the first thing I tried was following a set of operations to toggle a specific bit, keeping all the other bits the same. If there would be a method to do that, any case would be solvable. But that can't be done.

Comment: Following link may have your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489441/transforming-a-nxn-binary-matrix-to-a-zero-matrix-using-minimum-row-and-column-t?rq=1

Comment: In that problem, there are two operations. Toggle row and toggle column. That's quite different from the above problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: ["Converting a binary matrix to 0s by toggling rows and columns?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14169450/1009831).

Comment: @Rushil same idea can be extended.