# Transforming NxN binary matrix to zero matrix using minumum number of row-column toggles

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Similar to this problem: [Transforming a NxN binary matrix to a zero matrix using minimum row and column toggles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489441/transforming-a-nxn-binary-matrix-to-a-zero-matrix-using-minimum-row-and-column-t), but rather than having two operations (toggle row or toggle column), we only have one operation, which is to pick a coordinate (i,j), and toggle both the row and column that contains (i,j).

For example, toggling (0,0) of the matrix

```
|1 1 1|
|1 1 1|
|1 1 1|
```

will yield

```
|0 0 0|
|0 1 1|
|0 1 1|
```

I tried a recursive approach, where I tried toggling every element (i,j) that hasn't been previously toggled and passing the toggled matrix recursively to the function.  I find the minimum number of toggles, and return that result + 1.  However, the solution does not scale well with the size of the matrix (especially when the size > 10).

```
def toggle_matrix(matrix, row, col):
    new_matrix = [list(r) for r in matrix]
    for i in xrange(len(matrix)):
        new_matrix[i][col] ^= 1
        new_matrix[row][i] ^= 1
    new_matrix[row][col] ^= 1

    return tuple(tuple(r) for r in new_matrix)


def answer_recur(matrix, touched, cache):
    if all(c == 0 for r in matrix for c in r):
        return 0
    if matrix in cache:
        return cache[matrix]
    min_touches = float('inf')

    for row in xrange(len(matrix)):
        for col in xrange(len(matrix)):
            elem = (row, col)
            if elem in touched:
                continue
            min_touches = min(min_touches, answer_recur(toggle_matrix(matrix, row, col), touched | set([elem]), cache))
    cache[matrix] = min_touches + 1
    return min_touches + 1

def answer(matrix):
    matrix = tuple(tuple(r) for r in matrix)
    result = answer_recur(matrix, set(), {})
    if result == float('inf'):
        return -1
    return result
```

What is a better algorithm to tackle this problem that scales with the size of the matrix?